# $\sigma \colon (M[G];\in) \prec (N[H]; \in)$ implies $\sigma \restriction M \colon M \prec N$?

Tags: set-theory, forcing

Let $M,N$ be transitive models of sufficiently many $\operatorname{ZFC}$ axioms and let
$$
\sigma \colon M[G] \prec N[H]
$$
be an elementary embedding, where $G$ is $\mathbb P$-generic over $M$ for some forcing $\mathbb P \in M$, $H$ is $\mathbb Q := \sigma(\mathbb P)$-generic over $N$, $\sigma " G \subseteq H$ and $\sigma(G) = H$.

> **Question.** $\sigma \restriction M \colon M \prec N$ ?

I was able to prove the above in a more specific setting and now I'm wondering under which circumstances the general result might fail.

---

edit: I added the requirement $\sigma(G) = H$ as this is the case that I'm most interested in.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, because $M$ is definable with a parameter which depend on $\Bbb P$ in $M[G]$.

So $N$ is definable by the same formula say $\theta(x)$, with the image of the parameter (which is some $V_\delta$ for $\delta=|\Bbb P|^+$ if my memory serves me right).

Now suppose that $M\models\varphi(x)$, then $M[G]$ satisfies $\theta(x)$ and that the relativization of $\varphi(x)$ to the class defined by $\theta$ holds. Therefore $N[H]$ satisfies that as well, but $\theta$ defines $N$ in $N[H]$, so $N\models\varphi(\sigma(x))$.

Comment: You should *definitely* believe my answer is wrong, and nitpick the hell out of it. Then maybe it can be assumed to be true.

Comment: I think we have to require $\sigma(G) = H$ in addition for this to work, don't we? I'm also not quite sure how to isolate the $\mathbb P$-names of $M$ inside $M[G]$ without adding new names. If this can be done, then $M$ could be defined from $\mathbb P$ and $G$ inside $M[G]$.

Comment: First for the easy part. It's a theorem of Laver, that if $M[G]$ is a generic extension of $M$, then $M$ is definable from $(V_\delta)^M$ for an appropriate ordinal $\delta$. Without needing the $\Bbb P$-names and whatnot. Of course, after you have have the ground model, you also have the $\Bbb P$-names. As for the second part, I didn't see that $\sigma" G\subseteq H$ and not that $\sigma(G)=H$. But I think that elementarity dictates that $\sigma(G)=H$, no?

Comment: Thank you, I found Laver's paper [here](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0168007207000607). I'm not sure how to obtain $\sigma(G) = H$ directly, but using the definability of the ground model, it follows from Solovay's Theorem about mutually generic filters. Relativizing formulas and the modeling relation for $\Sigma_n$ formulas 'are well-behaved with respect to $\sigma$ (at least the ones I have in mind) and thus your argument should work. It is very similar to my proof, but instead of Laver's theorem, I had another way to define the ground model on both sides.

Comment: I guess that without knowing that $\sigma(G)=H$ before hand, you could argue that due to the ground model definability, the statement "The universe is a generic extension of $M$ by $\Bbb P$ with a generic filter $G$" must be true in $N[H]$. And since $H$ is $\Bbb Q$ generic, I think that - in conjunction with Solovay's aforementioned theorem - should give you that $\sigma(G)=H$, or that at least $N[\sigma(G)]=N[H]$. But again, treat my comment as false until you nitpick it clean.

Comment: Okay, now I'm not 100% sure that my previous comment is correct. All you should get is that $\sigma(M)$ is an inner model of $N[H]$ such that $N[H]$ is generic over. But I think that you can argue that if this is not $N$ itself, then $\sigma^{-1}(H)$ should give you a generic filter strictly larger than $G$. But again, nitpick this clean.

Comment: Let $H'=\sigma^{-1}(H)$, then $H'$ is an $M$-generic filter for $\Bbb P$, and $G\subseteq H'$. I don't see how $G\neq H'$ is even possible.

Comment: Right, it's not. If $p\in H'$, extend $p$ to a maximal antichain in $M$. Then for some $q$ in the antichain, $q\in G$, and therefore $q\in H'$. It follows that $q$ and $p$ are compatible, therefore $q=p$, so $H'\subseteq G$ as wanted.

Comment: Do we know that $H$ always has a preimage?

Comment: @Stefan: I meant the pointwise preimage.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/29308/discussion-between-stefan-and-asaf-karagila).

Comment: Sorry buddy, I don't do chat unless I really have to. You have my email if you want to delve deeper into this issue.